# In the book, Professional ASP.NET 4.5 in C# and VB, why does the CSS adjacent selector definition not match the example?

Tags: css, asp.net, html, html-lists

In chapter 2: **HTML5 and CSS3** of the book, *Professional ASP.NET 4.5 in C# and VB* by Jason N. Gaylord, Christian Wenz, and Pranav Rastogi, the adjacent selector section states, "Adjacent selectors enable you to select HTML elements that are immediately adjacent to another element type."

The section gives an example of needing to have a different color for every li after the first li in an unordered(ol) list.

Their CSS is below(Note: I added html so you can see the result):

```css
li
{
  color: maroon;
  }
li+li{
  color: silver;
  }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  </ol>
```

A google search defines adjacent as, "next to or adjoining something else."

**This would imply that the first element would be selected.**

Why is it not? It seems this is an ambiguous section in Chapter 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems this section has fallen victim to ambiguity.

w3.org clears this up in its selector table(Section 2.) defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), they say,"E + F --  an F element immediately preceded by an E element  "

This definition proves that the word adjacent only applies to the following element and not the leading element and explains why the first element of your list is not silver.